# MySQL Ordering by SubQuery

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by

I'm trying to pull a list of customers who place the most orders. I can't seem to figure out how to keep the list ordered by the sub query. Here's my query:

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  state.abbreviation AS state,
  country.abbreviation AS country
FROM main_customers AS c
  LEFT JOIN dict_stateProvince AS state ON c.state = state.id
  LEFT JOIN dict_country AS country ON c.country = country.id
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT customerId
               FROM main_orders
               GROUP BY customerId
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
LIMIT 50;
```

How do I keep the order of the main query the same as the subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery doesn't have a real order, because `IN` ignores the ordering.  But the intention is clear.  So, use a `join`:

```
SELECT c.*,
       state.abbreviation AS state,
       country.abbreviation AS country
FROM main_customers AS c JOIN
     (SELECT customerId, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM main_orders
      GROUP BY customerId
     ) mo
     ON mo.customerId = c.id LEFT JOIN
     dict_stateProvince AS state
     ON c.state = state.id LEFT JOIN
     dict_country AS country
     ON c.country = country.id
ORDER BY mo.cnt DESC;
```